# Want to get married in UK to a Jamaican

Tags: visas, uk, uk-citizens, weddings, jamaican-citizens

I have dual citizenship, British born, Jamaican by descent.
I am the administrator of my late fathers property in Jamaica and spend a lot of time there as a result. I've met the man i would like to marry, but want to marry in UK so the whole family can be there as opposed to one or two flying out for the event.

I'm a student, don't have much cash but i can prove i have a regular income albeit as a host from self employment He hasn't got a pot to p@ss in or a window to throw it out of, but will be getting added to a family members bank account as joint holder to show he has 'access' to a lil something.

I myself don't plan on living in UK as i want to return to Jamaica and live in the house my father left. I have no more dependents the children are grown (yay!)

Would the fact I'm a dual citizen, and the administrator of my dads house support I have plans to be back in Jamaica with my husband? If he states he has a child there (JA) that he wants to see grow up and he wants to be around his (father sisters etc) extended family show he has strong personal ties he must return for? 
I look forward to your thoughts.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not about traveling.

Comment: @Neusser Yes it is. The question is about the fiancé travelling to the UK to get married. It's a bit unfocussed at the moment but it is definitely about travelling.

Comment: @Neusser, im a new poster, forgive me

Comment: @MJffryes thank you, and i agree its currently a little unfocused. Can you point me in right direction where this question may be better discussed?

Comment: @LadyInRed Where are you resident right now? There are some restrictions on giving notice to get married in the U.K. https://www.gov.uk/marriages-civil-partnerships

Comment: "He hasn't got a pot to p@ss in or a window to throw it out of, but will be getting added to a family members bank account as joint holder to show he has 'access' to a lil something"

That's visa fraud right there. Why aren't you getting married in Jamaica if you want to return there anyway?

All this sounds highly suspicious.

Comment: Related question: https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/131539/religious-wedding-after-civil-wedding

Comment: @jwenting 'highly suspicious' is relative. Most people marry for love to poorer people and there are family that will support that by doing whatever the see as hekpful or neccessary. No 'funds parking here'. I'll concentrate on ticking all the boxes to satisfy suspicious minds who are in the position to grant the visa. Have a good day!

Comment: @Traveller, i'm residing in the UK at present, i go back and forth quite often due to no restrictions. I'd apply for marriage visa from UK, but also considering marrying in Jamaica legally, then getting that union blessed with friends and family in UK should he be granted standard visa. One reason i chose marriage visa is becaue there are rigid rules on income i must make whn applying for SVV. Otherwise they just ask for proof  a wedding has been arranged, proof of genuine relationship, access to a source of funds and some money paid towards the wedding.

Comment: @LadyInRed There are no rigid income rules for an SVV - the requirement is only to have sufficient funds to cover costs. The income rules apply to a Family visa https://www.gov.uk/uk-family-visa/proof-income

Comment: @LadyInRed the fund parking in combination with you bringing him to the UK rather than going to Jamaica despite claiming you plan to go to Jamaica afterwards is what makes it suspicious.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Your question is a little vague, but let me assume it boils down to "what do I need to do to get married to my Jamaican fiance in the UK?"

To be married in the UK your fiance needs a Marriage Visa. A normal tourist visa will not do it - your marriage would be illegal if you tried. Getting a Marriage Visa is harder than a tourist visa - he essentially has to show even more firmly than a tourist visa that he won't want to stay in the UK after the marriage. You can Google the requirements. I'm not expert enough to say if he would get a Marriage Visa or not.

One thing I should suggest, which you don't have to act on, is that it would be easier for the two of you to go to a registry office in Jamaica (or whatever the Jamaican equivalent is) and get legally married, and then come back to the UK and have a 'real' but not legally binding wedding. You can do the whole thing with vows, bridesmaids, white dresses, champagne and lots of family, just without the legal part, which will already have been done. This can be done on a Standard Visitor Visa, as long as you make it completely clear that you are already married. As someone married to a British citizen he should find it even easier to visit. This might also be a fallback option if your finance fails to get a Marriage Visa.

Comment: What kind of UK visa would they need in case they follow your suggestion in the last paragraph?

Comment: @mdd Standard visitor visa.

Comment: @DJClayworth If the Marriage visa were to be refused, wouldn’t that make refusal of a subsequent Standard Visitor visa application virtually certain? Being married to a British citizen doesn’t always make it easier to get a Visitor visa. Applicants have to satisfy the same basic eligibility requirements regarding genuine intention to visit/leave at the end of stay for both types. Perhaps the best option would be to forget the Marriage visa option and marry in Jamaica as you suggest, then apply for a SVV with the credible premise of visiting family after a recent wedding.

Comment: @Traveller, i appreciate that thank you. I too am aware it doesnt become easier to visit the uK because of marrige to a British citizen. The idea applying for a standard visitors visa after a wedding in order to meet the British side of 'our' family is very credible as we could have a blessing in the UK too in the presence  of our UK family and retun to jamaica where i would continue to oversee adminstration of late fathers property.